# HBase Thrift: how to connect to remote HBase master/cluster?

Tags: hbase, thrift, cloudera

Thanks to the Cloudera distribution, I have a HBase master/datanode + Thrift server running on a local machine, and can code and test HBase client programs and use it, no problem.

However, I now need to use Thrift in production, and I'm not able to find documentation on how to get Thrift running with a production HBase cluster.

From what I understand, I will need to run the hbase-thrift program on the **client node** since the Thrift program is just another intermediate client to HBase.

So I'm guessing that I have to be able to somehow specify the master node hostname/IP to HBase-Thrift? How would I do this?

Also, any suggestions on how to scale this up in production? Do I only need a setup like this:

```
Client <-> Thrift client <-> HBase Master <-> Multiple HBase workers
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Get it running

You don't have to run a Thrift server on your local machine, it can run anywhere but the RegionServers are usually a good place*. In the code you then connect to that server.

A Python example:

```
transport = TSocket.TSocket("random-regionserver", 9090)
```

Where you'd obviously replace the `random-regionserver` with one of the servers you're running the Thrift server on.

That server gets its configuration from the usual places. If you're using CDH then you'll find the configuration in `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml` and you'll need to add a property `hbase.zookeeper.quorum`:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>list of your zookeeper servers</value>
</property>
```

When you start the Thrift server from the downloaded Apache distribution this is similar except that the `hbase-site.xml` will probably sit in a different directory.

## Scaling it up

One easy way to scale up right now is to keep a list of all the Regionservers in your Thrift client and pick one at random on connect. Or you create multiple connections and use a random one each time. Some language bindings (i.e. PHP) have a `TSocketPool` where you can pass in all your servers. Otherwise there's some manual work you need to do.

Using this technique all reads and writes should be more or less distributed across the Thrift servers in your cluster. Each read or write operation arriving at a Thrift server will *still* be translated into a Java based API call from the Thrift server which then opens a network connection to the proper Regionserver(s) to perform the requested action.

That means that you won't get as good a performance as you would when you use the Java API. It *might* help if you cache region locations yourself and hit the appropriate Thrift server but even then an additional Java API call will be made even if it ends up on the local server. [HBASE-4460](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4460) would help with this scenario but this is *not* included in CDH3u4 or CDH4.

<sub>* There is an issue [HBASE-4460](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4460) which actually embeds a Thrift server in a Regionserver.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out. In relation to the scaling up part: so if I  randomly connect to different region servers directly and spread my writes to the different region servers, am I guaranteed to get consistent results when I read from them? (My HBase application is write-intensive, though I frequently have to do reads as well.)

Comment: That is a very good question. And no you won't get the best performance using a random assignment. I urge you to read the [HBASE-4460](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4460) issue about some of the problems. For reads (and writes) it could help if you cache the region locations and connect directly to that region server.

That said: Currently even if you write to the Thrift server on the Regionserver where your data will end up that Thrift server will still do a network request even if it ends up on `localhost`.

I'm afraid that's the current state of affairs (again see HBASE-4460).

Comment: I've edited the answer to incorporate my previous comment. I hope that makes it clearer and helps.

Comment: Just to follow up: I got this working! And am able to scale writes in HBase. :) It was not straight forward to get the cluster running, Thrift on the region servers, security rules, etc - but getting it running this way did the job! :) Thanks!

Comment: And sorry, one small follow-up question: if I randomly distribute the writes across region servers, how do the region servers sync up with each other - and do they even need to? How do I make queries once I'm done with my random-spread writing?

Comment: @Suman when you're distributing thrift calls in this fashion, the data is always written to the correct region, even if belongs to a different region than the one your thrift client is communicating with.

Comment: We are having the same problem (lots of write to HBase using python and thrift2), but even after connecting to multiple region servers directly before the puts, the writes just take as much time as when I only connect to the master server. I know this is a long time ago, but is there something I am missing?