# Scaling HBase writes on a cluster using Thrift

Tags: scalability, hbase, thrift

We're trying to scale up HBase writes on a cluster using Thrift. (Our HBase application is in Python, and hence needs Thrift.)

Despite increasing the number of nodes in the cluster, we are seeing the same write speeds.

First off, is the recommended strategy to run Thrift on:
1. The client?
2. The HBase master?
3. HBase region servers?

If on #1 or #2, will the client or HBase master take care of splitting the requests to the various region servers? It doesn't appear to in our case.

If #3, then I have to modify the client to write to the specific region servers, and randomize the writes. I can do this, but it seems to defeat the purpose of using HBase.

Any other tips on read/write scaling (especially with Thrift) are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer at these two questions, it looks like we'll go with #3 (write to the specific region servers, and randomize the writes):

- [Is it better to send data to hbase via one stream or via several servers concurrently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638270/is-it-better-to-send-data-to-hbase-via-one-stream-or-via-several-servers-concurr)
- [HBase Thrift: how to connect to remote HBase master/cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919618/hbase-thrift-how-to-connect-to-remote-hbase-master-cluster)

Comment: We are having the same problem (lots of write to HBase using python), but even after connecting to multiple region servers directly before putting, it doesn't seem like writes got faster. I know this is a long time ago, but are there other steps needed (like starting more Zookeeper servers)?

Answer (score 2):

In HBase to gain performance with node increase you should have a decent "rowkey" distribution. As long as you have "hot spots" (a very busy region server) in your cluster you would not gain anything from increasing your cluster size. checkout the [article](http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html) on row key design to start with.

If you don't need to read right away (if you are comfortable with async writes) you can check [asynch hbase client](https://github.com/stumbleupon/asynchbase) from stumbleupon for performance gain.